# Extending tables in SQL

Tags: sql

How to add a column to the table:

```
create table table1 (id integer primary key, field1 text)
```

? The column would be `field2 text` and the value for existing rows in this column should be `value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD field2 text;
UPDATE table1 SET field2='value';
```

Comment: Why not to use: alter table table 1 add field2 text default 'value'

Comment: Because he did not specify that he always wanted the value to be 'value'.  He just said "existing rows"...

Answer (score 2):

That would be the SQL syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype
```

In your case, you'd be looking at:

```
alter table table1 add field2 text
update table1 set field2 = 'value'
```